# How to deal with weekly schema updates on database production server? (ASPNet MVC and Entity Framework)

Tags: database, scrum, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, schema

I'm working with scrum methodology.

thus weekly schema updates are performed to the final product. However our customer is already populating the database. How can I update the database without dropping the tables?

How can I deal with these schema updates?

I am using DB First approach. this way I don't have Code First generated Migrations.

Comment: Write [DML statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) to perform the necessary database modifications.  Execute them upon upgrade.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think you mean [DDL statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)? (Well, probably a mixture of both).

Comment: @GertArnold: Yeah, I always get those two reversed.  I don't use them much in ordinary conversation unless the specific distinction needs to be made.